# how to calculate current prometheus TSDB storage size from /tsdb-status url

Tags: prometheus

I have this prometheus TSDB information, how can i know the current used storage in mb taked by this database ?.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To know your current used storage in MB, take a look at the following Prometheus metric:

```
prometheus_tsdb_storage_blocks_bytes / 1024 / 1024
```